# How can I implement a programmatic spinner menu for changing TTS language in my Android app?

Tags: java, android

How can I set a spinner menu for TTS (Text to Speech) in an Android app?

I use Java for my app and the spinner menu should have 8 languages, at the moment the only way to change the language is by changing the android system idiom, but I have to do this inside the logic of the app itself.

My goal is to create a spinner menu with the eight languages that are available and the user can select the TTS (Text to Speech) language in the spinner menu. Is there someone that can help me to implement this?
Because I don't know how implement this code.

Comment: Here you have the documentation about Spinners in Android Studio: [Spinners Android Java](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/spinner)

First you need to create a simple spinner with the languages you want to provide. Then you have to give the selected value to the TTS logic by parameter or another way. 

We can't do the whole work for you, but we can help you with specific problems.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's already a start for me.